# File.Delete doesn't throw exception inside Linux container

Tags: docker, .net-core, containers

I run same code in windows and linux container.
In windows container it throws exception as expected.
In linux container it doesn't.

```
var file = Path.Combine("folderdoesntexist", "doesntexist.txt");
File.Delete(file); // doesn't throw
```

I needed to add `File.Exists` check to make code work the same in windows and linux containers.
Why do I see this difference?

Comment: *Which* .NET Core version?

Comment: I use .net core 2.2